# Numerical solution of $k\nabla^2 p(\vec{x}) = \nabla(\vec{f}(\vec{x})p(\vec{x}))$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have the following equation:

$$k\nabla^2 p(\vec{x}) = \nabla(\vec{f}(\vec{x})p(\vec{x}))$$

where the constant $k>0$ and vector field $\vec{f}(\vec{x})$ are both known.

I wish to numerically solve $p(\vec{x})$ (rather, $p_{ijk}$) on a discrete $N^3$ grid subject to the boundary conditions $p_{ij1}=0$ and $p_{ijN}=1$, and lateral periodicity $p_{(i+N)jk}\equiv p_{ijk}$, $p_{i(j+N)k}\equiv p_{ijk}$.

What is the simplest method to achieve this? Finite difference seems unsuitable.

Comment: How many times do you need to solve it (i.e. is doing it fast a big factor)? How big is a typical value for $N$?

Comment: @Winther It does not need to be particularly fast (I'll only run it a dozen times). $N$ will be $\sim 10^2$. Cheers.

Comment: Then using a relaxation method is one option. Very easy to implement (but can be slow unless you implement multigrid acceleration - which is more work). You simply fix the value of the boundary cells in the $z$ direction (and leave them alone) and make an initial guess for the solution elsewhere. Then you sweep through your grid updating the values using e.g. Newton's method (and remembering periodic BC in the $xy$ plane). Repeat until the residual (the rms of the RHS - LHS of the equation) is low enough.

Comment: @Winther That looks promising. I'll give it a shot tomorrow and let you know how it turns out. Thanks.

Comment: @Winther I have implemented the Gauss-Seidel relaxation method, parallelised using checkerboxing. On 4 cores with $N=100$ it takes ~3,000 iterations (~1 minute) to converge. Cheers

Comment: Great! I'm glad it worked out. If you have time then it might be good to write up a short answer. Might be useful for other people in the future.